# How can a player lose experience?

Tags: powerplay-manager

I know how experience increase works in Powerplay-Manager. Every day a Player logs in he will get +1 experience for his team. But I have a friend that does not log in everyday. Last time I checked him, he had 151 experience. At this moment he has 149. How did he lose 2 experience points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Powerplay Manager Guide (I could find the same explanation on both the [Hockey](https://hockey.powerplaymanager.com/en/guide.html) and [Basketball](https://basketball.powerplaymanager.com/en/guide.html) pages):

> Every manager gains experience automatically by playing the game regularly. For each day that you log into your team you gain one point of manager experience. **For three days of inactivity you lose a point.** Until you get to 11 points you don't lose points for inactivity. Once you reach this mark you will not drop below it.

(Emphasis mine)

So, your friend lost 2 experience points because they have not logged into the game for at least 6 days.